# Where is the Program.cs or Startup.cs file in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-applications

I am trying to do an online library(as in an online book store) using ASP.NET MVC. I can't find the `Program.cs` file or the `Startup.cs` file.

I tried manually creating the Program.cs file but when I write the line

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

it does not find the `WebApplication` class.

I tried adding

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
```

but then I get another error:

> WebApplication' does not contain a definition for 'CreateBuilder

What should I do?

Comment: There's not enough information here to provide a proper answer.  If it's a "library" (and not a "framework" per se), your library shouldn't need to know anything about ASP.NET MVC or its startup point, since ASP.NET MVC will be calling your library, not the other way around.

Comment: There is no `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs` when you create a new ASP.NET MVC project, nor are they needed.  There is also no `CreateBuilder` method in the `WebApplication` class.  You may want to go through some tutorials for how to get started with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: you have to create net core mvc project, not just net mvc. Program.cs and Startup.cs files will be created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Serge made a good point in the comments.  Based on your notes, it looks like you have created a .NET 4 project.  What you want to do is recreate your project as an ASP.NET Core web app (.NET 5 or higher).  `Program.cs` will then be created automatically.

.NET 4 and 5 are completely different under the hood, so this distinction is important.  Rather than being an iteration, the latter was written from the ground up to be more scalable and support concepts like multiple platforms, microservices, and containers.